# How to change the center of a template

Tags: formatting

I would like to use this [Turabian-formatted Thesis/Dissertation template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/turabian-formatted-thesis-slash-dissertation/qkyvdqrsgmnf) hosted on Overleaf, but it seems that the center is off to the right. I wonder how to correct this at once including all the elements (text, page number, figure, table, etc)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please explain your issue better, for example with a screenshot and mark there the problem ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class reserves 0.5in (36pt) as binding offset.
If you don't need such space add `\setlength\oddsidemargin{0in}` after `\documentclass{turabian-thesis}` (or other suitable value)

You can visualize the layout by adding the package `layout` (`\usepackage{layout}`) and the `\layout` command after `\begin{document)`.

Original layout

[image: o]

Using `\setlength\oddsidemargin{0in}`. This will increase the available text width by 36pt.

[image: a]

If you want to keep the original text (433pt) width, add `\addtolength{\textwidth}{-0.5in}` to compensate.

[image: c]

Comment: Thank you very much Simon Dispa! I changed the center by adding \setlength\oddsidemargin{0in}.